# update view не сохраняет изменения в comment

Tags: django, python-3.6

пытаюсь реализовать возможность обновления и удаления комментариев пользователями которые зарегистрированы на сайте. но уже на моменте создание comment_update функции во view.py столкнулся стем что сохранение не происходит. 
должен ли я в update view обращаться уже не к посту а к коментарию и каким либо образом указывать его id?

вот views.py

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def comment_update(request, pk):
    template_name = 'blog/comment_update.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)

    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.user = request.user
        comment.save()
        return redirect('post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']
```

попробовал сначала пойти от простого и написал вот такой update_view:

```
def comment_update(request, pk):
    template = 'blog/comment_update.html'
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=comment)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('post-detail')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

но в таком виде выдает ошибку Page not found (404)

не могли бы объяснить почему так?

post-detail.html(comment part)

```
 <h4>comments:</h4>
    {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
      <comment class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle comment-author-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="comment-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ comment.user }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.timestamp|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
          </div>
          <p class="comment-body">{{ comment.body|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
        {# <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'comment-update' object.id %}">Update</a> #}
      </comment>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="new-comment">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info comment-btn" href="{% url 'comment-create' post.pk %}">New Comment</a>
    </div>
```

comment_form.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">comment</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: потому что у вас нет такой страницы, `post-detail`.

Comment: и нужно определить комментарий, который изменяешь.

Comment: дело в том что присоздании комментария редирект происходит именно на post-detail и все работает. подобная проблема с Page not found (404) появляется только в update.view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете не тот `instance`. В форму для комментов нужно передавать объект коммента, а не поста

```
# update view
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)

# form

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body']
```

Обновите `instance` c поста на коммент и все должно заработать

Что касается

> Попробовал сначала пойти от простого и написал вот такой update_view:

```
def comment_update(request, pk):
    template = 'blog/comment_update.html'
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=comment)
```

Вероятно вы передаете ID не коммента, а поста. Покажите шаблоны, тогда будет понятнее

---

UPD:

```
          <p class="comment-body">{{ comment.body|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
        {# <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'comment-update' object.id %}">Update</a> #}
      </comment>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="new-comment">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info comment-btn" href="{% url 'comment-create' post.pk %}">New Comment</a>
    </div>
```

> `{% url 'comment-update' object.id %}`

Тут вы говорите "хочу отправить на изменение коммента для поста такого то",что не верно, вам нужно править сам коммент

> `{% url 'comment-create' post.pk %}`

Тут все верно, мы хотим создать новый коммент для поста

Когда обновляете комментарий, используйте `comment` переменную а не `object`. `object` - это переменная, которая содержит объект, для которого создана view, в  вашем случае `Post`.

Update и Create views отличаются тем, что Create view работает с несуществующими объектами, и создает их, поэтому ему не нужно указывать ID объекта, который нужно сохранить, а Update view - работает с существующими объектами, и в отличие от Create view он сначала подгружает объект модели, для которого был передан ID. это касается как generic views так и ваших вроде функций

Что касается редиректа,то

> redirect('post-detail')

Вы забыли указать ID поста. Поправьте на

```
redirect('post-detail', pk=comment.post.pk)) # comment - это созданный или обновленный объект-комментарий
```

---

UPD:

И рекомандую проверять тип метода, ибо будут сыпаться ошибки, при обращении к POST методам при GET запросах